# Matlab GPU Computing: Process matrix as one unit

Tags: parallel-processing, gpgpu, matlab

I have a function called `fun` implemented as follows:

```
function result = fun( number , matrix)
 result = var( mean(matrix) + number ); // any processing not that exactly
end
```

Using the [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) `parallel Computing toolbox` I want to distribute it over the GPU on a set of number with the same matrix like the following code:

```
mat = magic(10);
numbers = 1:5;
gMat = gpuArray(mat);
gNumbers = gpuArray(numbers);
result = arrayfun(@fun,gNumbers,gMat); // Error here
```

It would be great if anyone can provide help with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case as originally posed, you can use MATLAB's [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/bsxfun.html) on the GPU. (The edited question cannot be addressed this way.)

```
mat = magic(5);
numbers = 1:5;
gMat = gpuArray(mat);
gNumbers = gpuArray(numbers);
result = bsxfun(@rdivide, gMat, gNumbers);
```

Note that I've used `@rdivide` directly rather than calling a separate function - you don't need to do that, but it makes things shorter. You could also use an anonymous function like so:

```
bsxfun(@(x,y) x./y, gMat, gNumbers)
```

Comment: I don't need division actually I want to do complex processing over numbers and this processing needs the matrix as a shared variable.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that right now. Both ARRAYFUN and BSXFUN currently require all inputs to be compatible sizes (or scalars), and the processing is done in an elementwise manner.

Comment: Can I manage to do so using `Jacket` or `GPUMat` or any other SDK for GPU Computing in matlab else the `Parallel Computing Toolbox` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway, you made a great help.

Comment: @SamehKamal: what processing do you need in your 'fun' ? maybe I can help you with Jacket or CUDAKernel from PCT

Comment: @asm: I need to enhance gray level image matrix  making every pixel in the new image matrix equal to the mean of window of pixels around it and the windows size is variable.